# Extracting the words starting with $ in the string in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I want to group the words starting with character $ from the text area content . This is the editor content. **Example paragrraph:**

```
Hi $firstname,

Please find the company credentials mentioned below:

Employee Name:
Employee ID:
Employee username: $username
Email ID: $email
Password: $password




Regards,
Administration Team
```

My Code:

```
$pattern = '/([$])\w+/';
preg_match($pattern, $input, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output is :

```
Array (
    [0] => $firstname 
    [1] => $ 
)
```

I need the output to be:

```
Array (
    [0] => $firstname 
    [1] => $username 
    [2]=>$email 
    [3]=>$password
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need the parenthesis around `[$]`. They are responsible for `$matches[1]` in your result.

Comment: `preg_match_all()` is what you need to get *all* matches.

Comment: Btw, what are you doing with the matches? Are you doing any kind of replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/\$\w+/', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `preg_match_all`. `preg_match` returns only first match. Also, fix your regexp to match the actual text:

```
$pattern = '/[$](\w+)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $input, $matches);
foreach($matches as $match) {
    echo $match[0] . ': ' . $match[1];
}
```

This will output:

```
$firstname : firstname
$username : username
$email : email
$password : password
```